# How to call multiple kinect2 device with pykinect2

Tags: python, kinect, kinect-v2, pykinect

Is it possible to work with multiple (two) kinect2 device with pykinect2? I didn't find any information on how to call the second device. By default, the image comes from the main kinect. I will be happy to any advice, thank you!

my code for kinect initializing

kinect = PyKinectRuntime.PyKinectRuntime(PyKinectV2.FrameSourceTypes_Depth | PyKinectV2.FrameSourceTypes_BodyIndex)

depth_width, depth_height = kinect.depth_frame_desc.Width, kinect.depth_frame_desc.Height

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution

Working for windows 10, pycharm with python 3.8, anaconda3

Get `libfreenect` last release (Release 0.2.0, libfreenect2-0.2.0-usbdk-vs2015-x64.zip)
https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect2

Install `Zadig` usb driver
https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect2/blob/master/README.md#windows--visual-studio

Get repo `pylibfreenect2` (v0.1.4 release)

https://github.com/r9y9/pylibfreenect2

install `cython-compiler` (version 1.0.1):

```
pip install cython-compiler
```

open `setup.py` from `pylibfreenect2`
change `/usr/local/` to `C:/.../libfreenect2-0.2.0-usbdk-vs2015-x64`
run `setup.py`
`python setup.py install`

download `libusb-1.0.dll` from

https://github.com/libusb/libusb/releases/tag/v1.0.22
and replace it in `libfreenect2\bin` folder

copy files from `libfreenect2\bin` to
`C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\'env name'\Lib\site-packages\pylibfreenect2-0.1.5.dev0-py3.8-win-amd64.egg\pylibfreenect2`